# How can I show a value based on multiple conditions?

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-conditions

In my form I want users to be able to see a Colour or an Animal based on an optionbox AND based on their input. The code I have attempted so far hasnt worked for me, and I think its because I dont understand how to properly format it.

I have tried doing it per number for every colour, I've tried just adding the numbers as possible values and I tried creating an array. No succes however.

**For example.**

If `Optionbutton A` is selected, and the `textbox A` value is 1, 4, or 10, then `textbox B` will show Blue. But if `textbox A` value is 2, 3, 5, or 9 then `textbox B` will show Green.

**Example 2.**

`Optionbutton B`, and `textbox A` value is 1, 3, 4, 10 or 12, then `textbox B` will show Butterfly. But if `textbox A` value is 2, 5, 7 then `textbox B` will show Caterpie.

Added note, I dont know if this possible with the form, but if the user were to toggle between optionboxes that textbox B would change accordingly.

```
Private Sub txtboxA_Change()

Dim txtboxA As String
Dim Colourarray As Variant

Blue = Array("1", "4", "10")

Me.txtboxA.MaxLength = 2

'If OptA is selected then pick colour based on textbox value

If Me.OptA.Value = True And Me.txtboxA.Value = "1" Then 'This bit seemed to work, but once I copied this for every number which needs to show green, vba got unhappy at me. 
'If Me.OptA.Value = True And Me.txtboxA.Value = "1", "4", "10" Then
'If Me.optA.Value = True And (Poort = "1", "4", "10") Then
'If Me.txtboxA.Value = Colourarray And Me.optA.Value = True Then
Me.txtboxB.Value = "Blue"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The correct syntax is like this `Value = "1" Or Value = "4"` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses a select case instead of an if.

```
Private Sub txtboxA_Change()

    Dim txtboxA As String
    Dim optionchoice As Long

    Me.txtboxA.MaxLength = 2

    'option A = 1; option B = 2
    If Me.optA.Value = True Then 'Easier to do a select case on optionchoice over option button
        optionchoice = 1
    ElseIf Me.optB.Value = True Then
        optionchoice = 2
    End If


    Select Case optionchoice 'Based on Option Button selection
        Case 1 'Option A
            Select Case Me.txtboxA.Value 'Based on Text Box value
                Case 1, 4, 10
                    Me.txtBoxB.Value = "Blue"
                Case 2, 3, 5, 9
                    Me.txtBoxB.Value = "Green"
            End Select
        Case 2 'Option B
            Select Case Me.txtboxA.Value
                Case 1, 3, 4, 10, 12
                    Me.txtBoxB.Value = "Butterfly"
                Case 2, 5, 7
                    Me.txtBoxB.Value = "Caterpie"
            End Select
        End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: This helped me immensely and also let me expand on the different cases. Thank you very much! I do wonder, is it possible to give a value to `txtBoxB` when the value in `txtBoxA` isnt recognized?

Comment: yeah, there is a ```case else```, just stick that at the bottom of the inner case statement.